# Debugging on Honeywell Dolphin from Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm developing a scanner app for [Honeywell Dolphin 7800](http://www.honeywellaidc.com/en-us/pages/Product.aspx?category=Enterprise%20Digital%20Assistant%20%28EDA%29&cat=HSM&pid=Dolphin7800A) devices, but can't figure out how to make eclipse detect the device. `Usb debugging` is enabled as well as `Allow non-Market applications` (also, device is showing `USB debugging connected` notification). I've tried restarting eclipse, adb server & device.

I'm working on `OSX`, and I'm guessing I need to edit `adb_usb.ini` as explained in [Kindle Fire Instructions](http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/sdk/Connecting_your_Kindle_Fire_to_ADB.pdf), but can't find the right `Usb vendor ID` in the [Android developer portal](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#VendorIds) nor in any Honeywell documentation.

Am I missing something obvious? Anyone succeeded connecting this device to eclipse?

Comment: use lsusb command to get vendor-id. Not sure if its available in OSX but its available in Linux.

Comment: Thanks @ArunkumarSharma! `lsusb` is not available in OSX, but I found an alternative way to get it in http://www.tekkie.ro/mobile-development/osx-list-usb-devices-lsusb-equivalent. After adding vendor-ids to adb_usb.ini, the device is finally detected! Please, feel free to post as answer for some karma :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem as you, and I managed to solve it. I wrote a little article in my blog, but it is in spanish:

http://www.hell-desk.com/android-debug-bridge-y-dispositivos-usb-no-encontrados/

I will try to write here a little resume:

Connect the honeywell device to your computer, and try to obtain the device ID. In windows this can be done in the device manager. The device id is a value "0C2E" in my case.

The thing is that you have to put these value in the adb_usb.ini file. Simply add the value at the end of the file.

After that:

```
adb kill-server

adb start-server
```

and **do not** execute android update adb, because the adb_usb.ini file will be erased again.

After that, try to list your devices. In my case it worked.

Hope this helps.

PS: take a look a the adb_usb.ini file that you can find in the USB drivers package (D7800_Android_USB_Driver_Package_v1.2). You can download them from the honeywell site. In the adb_usb.ini file you can see

```
[Google.NTx86]
;HSM D7800
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9018
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9018&MI_00
%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9018  

;HSM D7800
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_**0C2E**&PID_0BA0
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_0C2E&PID_0BA0&MI_00
%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0C2E&PID_0BA0
```

Thats the value that I can find in the device manager when I conect my d7800